# Can't expand root partition

Tags: linux, centos, lvm

Please advice. I trying to expand root partition on CentOS 8 in VMware virtual machine.

`lvdisplay` showing LV size 210 GiB.

```
  --- Logical volume ---
  LV Path                /dev/cl/root
  LV Name                root
  VG Name                cl
  LV UUID                r1Vl5U-xFsT-ENN1-Or1d-cfRB-jbeG-GatGcD
  LV Write Access        read/write
  LV Creation host, time localhost, 2019-10-30 18:41:53 +0300
  LV Status              available
  # open                 1
  LV Size                <210.00 GiB
  Current LE             53759
  Segments               2
  Allocation             inherit
  Read ahead sectors     auto
  - currently set to     8192
  Block device           253:0
```

But `df -h` showing size 50G.

```
Filesystem           Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
devtmpfs             397M     0  397M   0% /dev
tmpfs                411M     0  411M   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs                411M  5.7M  406M   2% /run
tmpfs                411M     0  411M   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/mapper/cl-root   50G   34G   17G  68% /
/dev/sda1            976M  177M  733M  20% /boot
/dev/mapper/cl-home   27G  224M   27G   1% /home
tmpfs                 83M     0   83M   0% /run/user/0
```

Then I try `resize2fs /dev/cl/root` and getting error

```
resize2fs 1.44.3 (10-July-2018)
resize2fs: Bad magic number in super-block while trying to open /dev/cl/root
Couldn't find valid filesystem superblock.
```

The `xfs_growfs /dev/cl/root` also did not working, with error `xfs_growfs: /dev/cl/root is not a mounted XFS filesystem`. Command `xfs_growfs /dev/mapper/cl-root` gives the same result.

`mount | grep /dev/mapper/cl-root` output:

```
/dev/mapper/cl-root on / type xfs rw,relatime,seclabel,attr2,inode64,noquota)
```

`file -Ls /dev/mapper/cl-root` output:

```
/dev/mapper/cl-root: SGI XFS filesystem data (blksz 4096, inosz 512, v2 dirs)
```

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski
Command `xfs_growfs /dev/mapper/cl-root` gives the same result - is not a mounted XFS filesystem`.

Comment: OK. I still know nothing about XFS but `man xfs_growfs` says the command requires a mountpoint, not a device node. In your case the mountpoint is `/`.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski
Aleluya! It's working! Thanks!

Comment: I'm glad. Please answer your own question then. I would, but I tend not to provide answers with commands I haven't verified by myself; and I have no experience with XFS at all. The answer should state what your mistake was and what the right command should be. There's no need to mention me in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @KamilMaciorowski, the problem was solved by a running `xfs_growfs /` command.  Because the `xfs_growfs` does accept not the device name as I did before, but the mount point.